# swift progessindicator for OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3, nsprogressindicator

i have a loop, which shows me all my address book contacts.
now i would like to show an NSProgressIndicator, which should show the progress from 0 (=start request contacts) until 100 (=all contacts requested). for this I tried something like this:

```
let addressBook = ABAddressBook.shared()
let people = addressBook?.people()
for person in people!  as! [ABPerson] {
   print(person)
   ProgressIndicator.increment(by: 0.22)
}
```

***why increment by 0.22?***

i have 451 contacts
100/451 = 0,22% per contact

but what happens?
i start my app. the print result will show each contact and when all contacts were requested > the progress indicator jumps to 100% directly.

what do I wrong?

Second try:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
   let addressBook = ABAddressBook.shared()
   let people = addressBook?.people()
   let stepPercent = 100 / (people?.count)!
   for person in people!  as! [ABPerson] {
      print(person)
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.ProgressIndicator.increment(by: Double(stepPercent))
   }
}
```

Comment: A reason could be that you have to dispatch the progress indicator line to the main thread.

Comment: i tried this (look at first post). now the progress bar fills slow from 0 to 100. but async. the progress is finish before all contacts are requested. this is logical for this. but not correct for my situation :(

Comment: Unrelated but if you set `maxValue` of the progress indicator to the number of people, you can increment by 1.

Comment: you are right. this is much better. thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let addressBook = ABAddressBook.shared()
            let people = addressBook?.people()
            print(Double((people?.count)!))
            let stepPercent = 100.00 / (Double((people?.count)!))
            print(stepPercent)
            for person in people!  as! [ABPerson] {
                print(person)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.ProgressIndicator.increment(by: Double(stepPercent))
            }
        }
```

thanks for support